# Devolver un valor capturado en una función

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void suma(){

    int num;
    cin >> num;

    cout << "EL" << num;
}

int main()
{
    suma();//tomar el num de aca y poder usarlo dento del main Ej: para poder    sumarlo con otro.

    int num2 = 10;

    int resultado;

    resultado = num + num2;//pero al compilar me sale 'num' was not declared in this scope y nose como solucionarlo o que puedo usar.

    cout << resultado;
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el recorrido [CLICK AQUI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: @the-breaker te sugiero visitar [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1059/463) para conocer de primera mano las etiquetas especiales que existen en [es.so] de cara a nuevos comentarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes retornar el valor del numero ingresado con return.  Para hacer eso necesitas que tu funcion retorne un int asi:

```
using namespace std;

int suma(){

 int num;
   cin >> num;

 cout << "EL" << num;
 return num
}

int main()
{
   int num = suma();//tomar el num de aca y poder usarlo dento del main Ej: para poder    sumarlo con otro.

int num2 = 10;

int resultado;

resultado = num + num2;

  cout << resultado;

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Me sacaste de un buen lio que me tenia bien estancado.

Comment: @JeremiasButassi si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema, por favor, márcala como solución (si pones el ratón debajo de *los puntos* de la respueta aparece un tick verde)